# How to split my java application into multiple jars based on modules

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, module

First my humble apologize for posting this questing in following tag. I don't know the exact tag for this.Please help me in this.

I have one java web application  developed in spring. Now i want to split the application into    multiple jars based on modules for different customer requirement.

I followed package structure for different modules
like

```
com.domain.abc.controller
com.domain.abc.service
com.domain.abc.dao

com.domain.xyz.controller
com.domain.xyz.service
com.domain.xyz.dao
```

I want to make these into two jars based on the module also having some packages and login module.

**EDIT**

Am using Eclipse and ANT

I don't know how and where to start. Please advice me.

Advance Thanks for your valuable comments.

Comment: Are you using Maven ?

Comment: are you using maven?
[EDIT]
lol same comment as @jeron_de_schutter.

if not, check the official website http://maven.apache.org/ and let us know if you need help

Comment: No I didnt use maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by modifying your build file (ant.xml if you use Ant, pom.xml if you use Maven, or if you use Eclipse just split your app into multiple projects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please suggest me some example or link to do that. Am using eclipse but dont know how to split into multiple projects

Comment: Ant has it own useful tutorial here:
http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

Take a few hours to play with it and after that use can build your app in whatever way you want. :-)

Normally it you use Eclipse, the file build.xml is what you need to start.

Comment: Ya thank you for your reply. While google i got that some softwares to do this. Is that so please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It would be valuable to know what tools you are using. For example, are you using Eclipse, Netbeans, or another IDE? Are you using an ANT project or a Maven project?

Currently I primarily use Netbeans, and if I was looking for a good example of how to structure multiple module projects, I would use the File->New Project menu, then create some of the projects from the "samples" section. Some of these projects have multiple modules, and there are examples different types of project.

There are also many sample projects on the web, such as https://java.net/downloads/glassfish-samples/

Comment: Sorry am using eclipse.